# Why is Microsoft Office Automation only available on Windows?

Tags: xojo

I'm building a Xojo desktop app and I'm trying to figure out if I can include a Word doc on my Xojo Window. However, I'm reading the documentation about Microsoft Office Automation and it seems like the plugins are only available for Windows. I'm using a mac, is there any way I could still use these features on my mac?

Comment: Run Parallels/etc?

Comment: @DaveNewton What if I want to distribute this program to other people who own macs or linux? Wouldn't it be a hassle for them to download Parallel so just they could use my Xojo program?

Comment: Yup. And expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to automate MS Word on Macintosh via Xojo because Microsoft removed VBA from the Mac editions a number of (Word) versions ago (circa 2011).

You might be able to automate Word on the Mac via AppleScripts.